# Requiring definite numbers in TextBox

Tags: vba, excel

I have a TextBox and I need to make user enter only `Single` numbers from -3 to 3.
No letters, no other symbols.

Comment: Use the textbox_keypress event.  Look at what is entered and allow or set the KeyAscii=0

Comment: @MatthewD Ok, thanks! But how to compare between two types of data? Input is `Long` and I need a `Single`

Comment: You might be better off using a combobox and only put the values you want in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First rule out the characters.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    'This will bail out if the backspace key is pressed. That way it will still work to backup in the textbox.
    If KeyAscii = 8 Then Exit Sub

    'This will allow only numaric values in the text box.
    'If (Chr(KeyAscii) < "0" Or Chr(KeyAscii) > "9") And KeyAscii <> 45 And KeyAscii <> 46 Then
    If (Chr(KeyAscii) < "0" Or Chr(KeyAscii) > "9") and  Chr(KeyAscii) <> "-" and  Chr(KeyAscii) <> "." Then
        KeyAscii = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Then check what was entered.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If val(TextBox1.text) < -3 then
        TextBox1.text = ""
    End If

    If val(TextBox1.text) > 3 then
        TextBox1.text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Something like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I need to use `Single` type, because I need the whole range between -3 and 3. (1.5; -1.25 etc). So I should add ASCII `.` to the exclusion

Comment: Sure. That should be 46. I added it.

Comment: Why do you use space in exclusion? 45 I mean

Comment: 45 is the negetive sign "-"  You can check against the chr() if you want. So Chr(KeyAscii) <> "-"

Answer (score 0):

You can very simply use the `TextBox_Exit` command like so:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

Select Case Me.TextBox1.Value

    Case Is = -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3

    Case Else:

        Me.TextBox1.Value = Null
        MsgBox "Only enter single digit numbers from -3 to 3"

End Select

End Sub
```